# How to shortly add 1 to several variables in Python?

Tags: python, iteration

If we have chance to do so:

```
a, b = 1, 4
```

Maybe we have chance to iterate several variables simultaneously like this?

```
a, b += 1, 2
```

Comment: No, but you can `a, b = a+1, b+2`

Comment: Or with walrus `(a := a + 1), (b := b + 2)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just looking for a shorthand one-liner, you could use `;` to separate statements:

```
a+=1; b+=2
```

Answer (score 2):

It is generally frowned upon in Python to put several statements together into a single one, unless they obviously belong together **and** this increases readability. In this case, none of these are true, so don't.

With lists, instead of separate variables, you can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) to increment like so:

```
a = [10, 20]
b = [1, 2]
c = [x + y for x, y in zip(a, b)]
print(c)
# [11, 22]
```

**REFERENCES:**

> `Sparse is better than dense.`
> `Readability counts.`

*PEP 20 -- The Zen of Python: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/*

Answer (score 0):

map over it

```
a,b=map((lambda x,y:x+y),*((a,b),(1,2)))
```

but its not short

Comment: Not downvoting (because I actually prefer this answer to stay as a warning for others), but **really**?

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.